# What is the proper way to type hint the return value of an @asynccontextmanager?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-asyncio, type-hinting, contextmanager

What is the proper way to add type hints for the return of a function with the `@asynccontextmanager` decorator?  Here are two attempts I made that both fail.

```py
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from typing import AsyncContextManager


async def caller():
    async with return_str() as i:
        print(i)

    async with return_AsyncContextManager() as j:
        print(j)


@asynccontextmanager
async def return_str() -> str:
    yield "hello"


@asynccontextmanager
async def return_AsyncContextManager() -> AsyncContextManager[str]:
    yield "world"
```

For both `i` and `j` [Pylance](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release) in vscode shows type `Any`.  Other ideas I've considered:

- I thought maybe I could pass in the type info to the decorator itself (like `@asynccontextmanager(cls=str)`, but I can't find any examples of that, or any description of the args I could pass in.
- `async with return_str() as i: # type: str` doesn't work either.  Even if it did, I'd rather hint at the function definition, not at every invocation.  Type comments are not very DRY.
- I tried to create an `AsyncContextManager` class with `__aenter()__` and `__aexit()__` functions, but was not successful.  I would fall back to that if it worked, but I'd prefer to make the decorator work because it's much more concise.

Here's a screencap of me hovering the `return_AsyncContextManager()` function, and showing the Pylance popup saying it returns `AsyncContextManager[_T]`
[image]

Comment: remove parentheses in `asynccontextmanager` call, its argument should be function itself, not a type

Comment: Yeah, I've tried a lot of different iterations.  I accidentally pasted in some of the sillier attempts.  Even with standard `@asynccontextmanager` (no parens) decorators, it exhibits the same `Any` type inference.  I've updated the question to show the standard code.

Comment: It's a good idea to not trust what `pylance` is telling, because it's an unreliable tool full of bugs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to hint `AsyncIterator` as the return type, like this:

```py
@asynccontextmanager
async def my_acm() -> AsyncIterator[str]:
    yield "this works"


async def caller():
    async with my_acm() as val:
        print(val)
```

This is because the `yield` keyword is used to create generators.  Consider:

```py
def a_number_generator():
    for x in range(10):  # type: int
        yield x

g = a_number_generator() # g is type Generator[int]
```

This makes sense given the [type hints for @asynccontextgenerator](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/contextlib.pyi#L45):
`asynccontextmanager(func: Callable[..., AsyncIterator[_T]]) -> Callable[..., AsyncContextManager[_T]]`

That's a lot to parse but it says that the `asynccontextgenerator` takes a function which returns `AsyncIterator` and transforms it into a new function that returns `AsyncContextManager`  A generic type `_T` is preserved as well.

Here is a screenshot showing the type hint transferring into the caller function.

[image]